# $ne and $nin not working on Meteor Backend

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I've noticed that wherever I have a publication definition involving $ne or $nin, it has no effect. For example, I define a publication as

```
Meteor.publish('testing', function() {
    return Courses.find({name: {$ne: 'Course A'}})
});
```

I have made sure that I have a course with name "Course A", however, when I subscribe like this on the client:

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe("testing").subscribe(() => {
        console.log(Courses.find().fetch())
    });
```

I get every single course in the database (including the one with name "Course A"). In case it's relevant, my definition for Courses is: `export const Courses = new MongoObservable.Collection<Course>('courses');`.
Is my selector wrong, or is it a bug with Meteor? When I run the same selector on the client side, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did u check if you disabled/remove autopublish package? You can check it inside .meteor/packages file. If yes, then remove it so meteor respect your publications.

Let me know if this solves your problem. Thanks!

Update 1:
Try this:

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe("testing").subscribe(() => {
    console.log(Courses.find({name: {$ne: 'Course A'}}).fetch());
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I have, and all my other publications work (ones where $nin and $ne are not used)

Comment: by "Yeah, I have" you mean you still have the autopublish package? Did u try removing it? Also if that doesn't work, you can try modifying you subscription in to this:

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe("testing").subscribe(() => {
        console.log(Courses.find({name: {$ne: 'Course A'}}).fetch());
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I DO NOT have the autopublish package. My bad for the confusion.

Comment: Also, the code you commented works perfectly fine, the results are as expected. The only place where the $ne or $nin doesn't work are in the publish function.

Comment: hmmm that's weird. Maybe you can stick with the modified subscription for now. :)

Comment: Alright, makes sense. It's really nothing big - I just thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the help though